# If-Then-Else Across Table in Formula/Group

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to evaluate multiple conditions for each distinct `record_id`

I have over 20 columns in my table where each `record_id` is scored yes/no
based on case statements from a view, for ex:

*record_id --- is_up --- is_down --- is_left --- is_right

1234 --- no --- yes --- no --- yes*

I started using an if / then / else statement like:

```
if is_up = yes then "Its Up" else   
if is_down = yes then "Its Down else   
if is_left = yes then "Its Left else     
if is_right = yes then "Its Right" else "Not"
```

This works until a record meets multiple conditions, then the report only displays the record when the first condition is met

I would like to group on this formula and display all records where each condition is met, so if record_id 3344 has a "yes" in each - it displays under each group

ideally, I would like to avoid having multiple sub-reports for each case

open to any suggestions or ideas, thanks!

Comment: in short you want to call a condition/formula for 20 times because of the number of fields that holds this value?

Comment: hm.. i don't think so - it would be a different condition on each if/then statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a condition/function 20 times for the 20 columns that you want to transform then use a sql command datasource and not table based.

You'll need following:

1. A sql scalar function to return the result of a condition or use CASE statement for all 20 fields or IIF (SQL Server 2012 and over)
2. Your main sql statement

Sample code

```
Select 
translate(col1) t1,
translate(col2) t2
translate(col3) t3,
translate(col4) t4,
....t20
From table
```

Or

```
Select iif(col1='condition',truevale,falsevalue) t1,.....t20 from table
```

Or CASE